# using login view and UserCreationForm at the same time on the one page

Tags: python, django, authentication

I struggle with Django for a few days and the most unpeasant thing is that it actually hard to find answer on Internet. I'm practicing with login/register forms and authentication in general. Firstly, I had my own login and registration form but when I found out that Django has it's own built-in login system from `django.contrib.auth.views`, I tried to use one and stuck with the problem that `login` is the whole view and it ignores my registration form. So, simply it has to look like a block where I can switch to login or to register, depending on my needs but the only login form appears. I am looking for the solution which allows me to combine both forms on the one one page.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', login, {'template_name':'index.html'}),
path('accounts/', views.account)]
```

**forms.py:**

```
class login_form(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter email',
        }
    ))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter password',
        }
    ) )
class register_form(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter email'
        }
    ))
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'placeholder':'Enter password'
        }
    ))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Confirm password'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(register_form, self).save(commit=False)

        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.username = user.email
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can create view with two forms in page

```
def user_auth(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_type = request.POST.get('type', None)
        if form_type == 'login':
            login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if login_form.is_valid():
                # do what you want
        if form_type == 'registration':
            registration_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if registration_form.is_valid():
                # do what you want
        else:
            # unrecognize type
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
        registration_form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'login_form': login_form, 'registration_form': registration_form}
        return render(request, 'your_template_name.html', context)
```

Then in your template:

```
<form action='{% url 'name_of_your_view' %}' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='type' value='login' style='display: none'>
    {{ login_form }}
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<form action='{% url 'name_of_your_view' %}' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='type' value='registration' style='display: none'>
    {{ registration_form }}
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And in your JS code hide or show one of them depends of what your want.

Comment: So I can't use login from django.contrib.auth.views because it is a whole view and not a form? So I need to define my own form and then implement the logic of authentication in model?

Comment: I mean that I use `login` view straight from **urls.py**, omitting **views.py**, so I need to access `login` from **views.py**.

Comment: @AntonSachko Maybe django allows to use core django auth views, but i don't sure about it.